# "Enrich" Spark DataFrame from another DF (or from HBase)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hbase

I am not sure this is the right title so feel free to suggest an edit. Btw, I'm really new to Scala and Spark.

Basically, I have a DF `df_1` looking like this:

`| ID | name | city_id |
 | 0  | "abc"| 123    |
 | 1  | "cba"| 124    |
 ...`

The `city_id` is a key in a huge HBase:

123; New York; .... 124; Los Angeles; .... etc.

The result should be `df_1`:

`| ID | name | city_id |
 | 0  | "abc"| New York|
 | 1  | "cba"| Los Angeles|
 ...`

My approach was to create an external Hive table on top of HBase with the columns I need. But then again I do not know how to join them in the most efficient manner.

I suppose there is a way to do it dirrectly from HBase, but again I do not know how.

Any hint is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create an itermediate hive table over hbase. Spark sql can deal with all kind of unstructured data directly. Just load hbase data into a dataframe with the [hbase data source](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc)

Once you have the proper hbase dataframe use the following
sample spark-scala code to get the joined dataframe:

```
val df=Seq((0,"abc",123),(1,"cda",124),(2,"dsd",125),(3,"gft",126),(4,"dty",127)).toDF("ID","name","city_id")

 val hbaseDF=Seq((123,"New York"),(124,"Los Angeles"),(125,"Chicago"),(126,"Seattle")).toDF("city_id","city_name")

 df.join(hbaseDF,Seq("city_id"),"inner").drop("city_id").show()
```